# How to get marginal effects for categorical variables in mlogit?

Tags: r, multinomial, mlogit, marginal-effects

I want to compute marginal effects for a `"mlogit"` object where explanatory variables is categorical (factors). While with numerical data `effects()` throws something, with categorical data it won't.

For simplicity I show a bivariate example below.

#### numeric variables

```
# with mlogit
library(mlogit)
ml.dat <- mlogit.data(df3, choice="y", shape="wide")
fit.mnl <- mlogit(y ~ 1 | x, data=ml.dat)

head(effects(fit.mnl, covariate="x", data=ml.dat))
#         FALSE       TRUE
# 1 -0.01534581 0.01534581
# 2 -0.01534581 0.01534581
# 3 -0.20629452 0.20629452
# 4 -0.06903946 0.06903946
# 5 -0.24174312 0.24174312
# 6 -0.39306240 0.39306240

# with glm
fit.glm <- glm(y ~ x, df3, family = binomial)

head(effects(fit.glm))
# (Intercept)           x                                                 
#  -0.2992979  -4.8449254   2.3394989   0.2020127   0.4616640   1.0499595
```

#### factor variables

```
# transform to factor
df3F <- within(df3, x <- factor(x))
class(df3F$x) == "factor"
# [1] TRUE
```

While `glm()` still throws something,

```
# with glm
fit.glmF <- glm(y ~ x, df3F, family = binomial)

head(effects(fit.glmF))
# (Intercept)           x2           x3           x4           x5           x6 
# 0.115076511 -0.002568206 -0.002568206 -0.003145397 -0.003631992 -0.006290794
```

the `mlogit()` approach

```
# with mlogit
ml.datF <- mlogit.data(df3F, choice="y", shape="wide")
fit.mnlF <- mlogit(y ~ 1 | x, data=ml.datF)

head(effects(fit.mnlF, covariate="x", data=ml.datF))
```

throws this **error**:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(data[, covariate], eps) :

 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

**How could I solve this?**

I already tried to manipulate `effects.mlogit()` with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25833121/6574038) but it didn't help to solve my problem.

*Note:* This question is related to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54079553/6574038), which I want to apply to categorical explanatory variables.

---

#### edit

(To demonstrate the issue when applying the given solution to an underlying problem related to a question linked above. See comments.)

```
# new example ----
library(mlogit)
ml.d <- mlogit.data(df1, choice="y", shape="wide")
ml.fit <- mlogit(y ~ 1 | factor(x), reflevel="1", data=ml.d)

AME.fun2 <- function(betas) {
  aux <- model.matrix(y ~ x, df1)[, -1]
  ml.datF <- mlogit.data(data.frame(y=df1$y, aux), 
                         choice="y", shape="wide")
  frml <- mFormula(formula(paste("y ~ 1 |", paste(colnames(aux), 
                                                  collapse=" + "))))
  fit.mnlF <- mlogit(frml, data=ml.datF)
  fit.mnlF$coefficients <- betas  # probably?
  colMeans(effects(fit.mnlF, covariate="x2", data=ml.datF))  # first co-factor?
}

(AME.mnl <- AME.fun2(ml.fit$coefficients))

require(numDeriv)
grad <- jacobian(AME.fun2, ml.fit$coef)
(AME.mnl.se <- matrix(sqrt(diag(grad %*% vcov(ml.fit) %*% t(grad))), 
                      nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
AME.mnl / AME.mnl.se
#  doesn't work yet though...

# probably "true" values, obtained from Stata:
# # ame
#         1      2      3      4      5
# 1.     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA   
# 2. -0.400  0.121 0.0971  0.113 0.0686   
# 3. -0.500 -0.179 0.0390  0.166 0.474 
#
# # z-values
#        1     2     3     4     5
# 1.    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2. -3.86  1.25  1.08  1.36  0.99
# 3. -5.29 -2.47  0.37  1.49  4.06
```

---

#### data

```
df3 <- structure(list(x = c(11, 11, 7, 10, 9, 8, 9, 6, 9, 9, 8, 9, 11, 
7, 8, 11, 12, 5, 8, 8, 11, 6, 13, 12, 5, 8, 7, 11, 8, 10, 9, 
10, 7, 9, 2, 10, 3, 6, 11, 9, 7, 8, 4, 12, 8, 12, 11, 9, 12, 
9, 7, 7, 7, 10, 4, 10, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 10, 8, 10, 6, 7, 10, 
9, 6, 4, 6, 6, 8, 6, 9, 3, 7, 8, 2, 8, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 
5, 7, 9, 1, 6, 11, 11, 9, 7, 8, 9, 9), y = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))

> summary(df3)
       x             y          
 Min.   : 1.00   Mode :logical  
 1st Qu.: 7.00   FALSE:48       
 Median : 8.00   TRUE :52       
 Mean   : 8.08                  
 3rd Qu.:10.00                  
 Max.   :13.00  

df1 <- structure(list(y = c(5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 
5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 
5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
5, 2), x = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of expected that `effects` doesn't work with factors since otherwise the output would contain another dimension, somewhat complicating the results, and it is quite reasonable that, just like in my solution below, one may instead want effects only for a certain factor level, rather than all the levels. Also, as I explain below, the marginal effects in the case of  categorical variables are not uniquely defined, so that would be an additional complication for `effects`.

A natural workaround is to manually convert the factor variables into a series of dummy variables as in

```
aux <- model.matrix(y ~ x, df3F)[, -1]
head(aux)
#   x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13
# 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0
# 2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0
# 3  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0
# 4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   0
# 5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0
# 6  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0
```

so that the data then is

```
ml.datF <- mlogit.data(data.frame(y = df3F$y, aux), choice = "y", shape = "wide")
```

We also need to construct the formula manually with

```
frml <- mFormula(formula(paste("y ~ 1 |", paste(colnames(aux), collapse = " + "))))
```

So far so good. Now if we run

```
fit.mnlF <- mlogit(frml, data = ml.datF)
head(effects(fit.mnlF, covariate = "x2", data = ml.datF))
#           FALSE         TRUE
# 1 -1.618544e-15 0.000000e+00
# 2 -1.618544e-15 0.000000e+00
# 3 -7.220891e-08 7.221446e-08
# 4 -1.618544e-15 0.000000e+00
# 5 -5.881129e-08 5.880851e-08
# 6 -8.293366e-08 8.293366e-08
```

then the results are not correct. What `effects` did here is that it saw `x2` as a *continuous* variable and computed the usual marginal effect for those cases. Namely, if the coefficient corresponding to `x2` is b2 and our model is f(x,b2), `effects` computed the derivative of f with respect to b2 and evaluated at each observed vector x<sub>i</sub>. This is wrong because `x2` only takes values 0 and 1, not something around 0 or around 1, which is what taking the derivate assumes (the concept of a limit)! For instance, consider your other dataset `df1`. In that case we incorrectly get

```
colMeans(effects(fit.mnlF, covariate = "x2", data = ml.datF))
#           1           2           3           4           5 
# -0.25258378  0.07364406  0.05336283  0.07893391  0.04664298
```

Here's another way (using derivative approximation) to get this incorrect result:

```
temp <- ml.datF
temp$x2 <- temp$x2 + 0.0001
colMeans(predict(fit.mnlF, newdata = temp, type = "probabilities") - 
             predict(fit.mnlF, newdata = ml.datF, type = "probabilities")) / 0.0001
#           1           2           3           4           5 
# -0.25257597  0.07364089  0.05336032  0.07893273  0.04664202
```

Instead of using `effects`, I computed the wrong marginal effects by hand by using `predict` twice: the result is mean({fitted probability with x2new = x2old + 0.0001} - {fitted probability with x2new = x2old}) / 0.0001. That is, we looked at the change in the predicted probability by moving `x2` up by 0.0001, which is either from 0 to 0.0001 or from 1 to 0.0001. Both of those don't make sense. Of course, we shouldn't expect anything else from `effects` since `x2` in the data is numeric.

So then the question is how to compute right (average) marginal effects. As I said, marginal effect for categorical variables is not uniquely defined. Suppose that x_i is whether an individual i has a job and y_i is whether they have a car. So, then there are at least the following six things to consider.

1. Effect on the probability of y_i = 1 when going from x_i=0 to x_i=1.
2. When going from x_i=0 to x_i (the observed value).
3. From x_i to 1.

Now when we are interested in average marginal effects, we may want to average only over those individuals for whom the change in 1-3 makes a difference. That is,

4. From x_i=0 to x_i=1 if the observed value isn't 1.
5. From x_i=0 to x_i if the observed value isn't 0.
6. From x_i to 1 if the observed value isn't 1.

According to your results, Stata uses option 5, so I'll reproduce the same results, but it is straightforward to implement any other option, and I suggest to think which ones are interesting in your particular application.

```
AME.fun2 <- function(betas) {
  aux <- model.matrix(y ~ x, df1)[, -1]
  ml.datF <- mlogit.data(data.frame(y = df1$y, aux), choice="y", shape="wide")
  frml <- mFormula(formula(paste("y ~ 1 |", paste(colnames(aux), collapse=" + "))))
  fit.mnlF <- mlogit(frml, data = ml.datF)
  fit.mnlF$coefficients <- betas
  aux <- ml.datF # Auxiliary dataset
  aux$x3 <- 0 # Going from 0 to the observed x_i
  idx <- unique(aux[aux$x3 != ml.datF$x3, "chid"]) # Where does it make a change?
  actual <- predict(fit.mnlF, newdata = ml.datF)
  counterfactual <- predict(fit.mnlF, newdata = aux)
  colMeans(actual[idx, ] - counterfactual[idx, ])
}
(AME.mnl <- AME.fun2(ml.fit$coefficients))
#           1           2           3           4           5 
# -0.50000000 -0.17857142  0.03896104  0.16558441  0.47402597 

require(numDeriv)
grad <- jacobian(AME.fun2, ml.fit$coef)
AME.mnl.se <- matrix(sqrt(diag(grad %*% vcov(ml.fit) %*% t(grad))), nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)
AME.mnl / AME.mnl.se
#           [,1]      [,2]    [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
# [1,] -5.291503 -2.467176 0.36922 1.485058 4.058994
```

Comment: Thanks for answering again! I'm sure you imagined me applying that to my [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54079553/6574038) where I ran into trouble to summarize this into AMEs. And you are right, I wondered why to (only) use `"x3"` as a covariate, whereby I consider your argument very plausible. Indeed it'll take additional time to discuss the results, for the moment I just want to make R ready for battle. I made an edit to show the follow-up problem and added data `df1` that mimicks my real ones (`x`=clusters, by the way). Maybe you can guide me to the end?

Comment: @jay.sf, your code seems to work for me (except for the warnings at the end due to the number of dimensions). But as I understand AME and z-values are different than expected, right? If so, I have a good idea where the problem in my current answer leading to that is.. Are those "true" values again corresponding to this exact `df1`?

Comment: Yes, the AMEs go at least in the right direction (assumed they are only for `x2`), but the former result without factors was much more "true". Whereas the SE and z-values seem to be quite off and yield wrong dimensions. I'd like to have the former output with two data frames, AMEs and z-values. Yes, these are again these " true" values.

Comment: @jay.sf, ok, I already know how everything works and how to fix it but first.. Do you have a definition for AME that you care about? Or do you just want to replicate Stata's result? I'm asking because it is something not uniquely defined. For a given individual i and the dummy variable taking value x_i, there are several ME that you may want: 1) ME of going from 0 to 1; 2) from 0 to x_i; 3) from x_i to 1; 4) option 1) only for those who are not yet at 1; 5) option 2) for those who are not yet at 0; 6) option 3) for those not at 1. I deduced that your "true" results use 5).

Comment: Great. Ok, I'm not sure about the categories you've given, but the AMEs should show the probabilities for each `x` cluster to end in one of the `y` categories. The given Stata values should be okay since they are *average* marginal effects (just `margins, dydx(*)`) resp. discrete change effects, and not the conditional ones (`atmeans`).

Comment: Thank you for your time @Julius Vainora and your detailed answer, I've learned a lot from you, +1! I appreciate programming with R very much, and as much as possible from scratch. Because things don't just come out of a black box, you understand better what's really going on.

Comment: @jay.sf, no problem, I should've written this answer before, there was no way that the original one with `effects` could be right. Looking forward to your other econometric questions!